# All permutations of a MutableArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, permutation

I am looking for a algorithm in Objective C:
I want to find all the permutations of a `NSMutable` of 30 numbers:

```
(1,2,3,4....29,30)
```

each possibility must be in a `MutableArray` for another test and after the test keep it or not.
What is the best and fast way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this a question for a job interview? :-)

Comment: Do a search. This question really has nothing to do with Objective-C. Find any algorithm to find the permutations and then make an attempt to apply it to your code. Update your question with your attempt and describe what issue you are having.